# Having Trouble Identifying Memory Leaks in Singly Linked List (with Dr. Memory) C++

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to memory allocation and freeing(deleting) so I apologize if the solution is clear. I have this program that creates and manipulates a linked list(add to front, back, insert, free, etc) and when I run Dr. Memory I get 2 LEAK errors:

```
 ~Dr.M~~ Error #1: LEAK 16 direct bytes 0x00000000032614c0-0x00000000032614d0 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 replace_operator_new                 [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2899]
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 msvcrt.dll!ftell                    +0x19e    (0x00007ff9c2dedaaf <msvcrt.dll+0x4daaf>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 2 msvcrt.dll!_iob_func                +0x51     (0x00007ff9c2ddcb22 <msvcrt.dll+0x3cb22>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 3 msvcrt.dll!fwrite                   +0x79     (0x00007ff9c2dedbaa <msvcrt.dll+0x4dbaa>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 4 libstdc++-6.dll!?                   +0x0      (0x000000006fcfb673 <libstdc++-6.dll+0xbb673>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 5 CS170::ListLab::Insert               [C:\Users\.../List.cpp:123]
~~Dr.M~~ # 6 libstdc++-6.dll!?                   +0x0      (0x000000006fcad5d2 <libstdc++-6.dll+0x6d5d2>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 7 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk    +0x13     (0x00007ff9c2f03034 <KERNEL32.dll+0x13034>)
~~Dr.M~~
~~Dr.M~~ Error #2: LEAK 16 direct bytes 0x00000000032615b0-0x00000000032615c0 + 0 indirect bytes
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 replace_operator_new                    [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2899]
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 msvcrt.dll!write                       +0xb6     (0x00007ff9c2dbf717 <msvcrt.dll+0x1f717>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 2 msvcrt.dll!flsbuf                      +0x160    (0x00007ff9c2de6da1 <msvcrt.dll+0x46da1>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 3 libstdc++-6.dll!?                      +0x0      (0x000000006fcae568 <libstdc++-6.dll+0x6e568>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 4 libstdc++-6.dll!?                      +0x0      (0x000000006fcad5d2 <libstdc++-6.dll+0x6d5d2>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 5 CS170::ListLab::Insert                  [C:\Users\.../List.cpp:123]
~~Dr.M~~ # 6 CS170::ListLab::PrintList               [C:/mingw/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/ostream:613]
~~Dr.M~~ # 7 libstdc++-6.dll!?                      +0x0      (0x000000006fcad5d2 <libstdc++-6.dll+0x6d5d2>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 8 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk       +0x13     (0x00007ff9c2f03034 <KERNEL32.dll+0x13034>)
~~Dr.M~~ Fetching 1 symbol files...
~~Dr.M~~ [1/1] Fetching symbols for C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
~~Dr.M~~ Fetched 0 symbol files successfully
```

It is pointing to this function:

```
void Insert(Node **pList, int value, int position)
{
  struct Node *current = *pList;

  struct Node *newNode = MakeNode(value);

  int count = 0;

  if(position == 0)
  {
    *pList = newNode;
    (*pList)->next = current;

  }
  else
  {

    struct Node *previous = new Node; /*** this is line 123 ***/

    while(current->next != NULL && count != position)
    {
      if(count == (position - 1))
      {
        previous = current;
      }

      current = current->next;
      count++;
    }

    previous->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = current;
  }

  if(current->next == NULL && position == count+1)
  {
    newNode->next = NULL;

    while(current->next)
    {
      current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = newNode;
  }

  if(position > count + 1)
  {
    return;
  }
}
```

I thought that it was a problem with freeing the previous pointer but when I try to delete it, it just causes more problems. I am not sure how to fix this. Again, I apologize if it is obvious. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `struct Node *previous = new Node;` do you need a new here? Seems like you just want a pointer. Not a new node.

Comment: @drescherjm But I use "previous->next" so wouldn't I need to allocate memory for it?

Comment: @adsf No, because it's already been allocated, you just want to change the location.

Comment: You also lose track of the new Node, when you do 'previous = current'

Comment: @drescherjm Oh, I see. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You should rethink that function. If `while(current->next != NULL && count != position)` does not enter, `previous->next = newNode` doesn't do you any good. `previous` won't be pointing anywhere useful.

Comment: The best way that I know of ro get a grip on linked lists is by drawing a lot of pictures. Draw the list. Draw all of the steps you need to do to complete an operation. When you are debugging, follow your coded instructions step by step and try to draw the same list. If you can't not only have you found the bug, you should also know what step you got wrong and what you needed to do instead.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the advice. Drawing diagrams really does help!

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Memory is telling you that you have a leak on line 123. You have labelled line 123 in your code. On line 123 you are allocating a new `Node`. In the code you posted you are not deleting the memory that you allocated on line 123.

As you're using C++, to use a linked list, you should just:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

...

std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodeList;
nodeList.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>());
```

Comment: Or better, `std::list<Node>` and get rid of the pointers altogether